# Set NTFS file permissions in java

Tags: java

How to set NTFS file permissions in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be possible with NIO2 in Java 7. Look at this tutorial http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html, especially getAcl() and setAcl() methods.